# StringBuilder from String in Java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

Assume that we have a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` like below:

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("xxx");
StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer("xxx");
```

We can get a `String` from the above variables using the `toString()` method.

I know that `toString` is an over-ridden method in both classes.

Assume also that we have a `String` like below:

```
String s3 = "xxx";
```

I can't get a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` using `toStringBuilder()` or `toStringBuffer()`. Instead, the way we can achieve is like below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s3);
```

Is there a reason why `toStringBuilder()`/`toStringBuffer()` is not defined and is there any other effective way to get a `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` from `String`.

Comment: What benefit would there be, in your view? What do you dislike about calling `new StringBuilder(s)`?

Comment: A mutable `StringBuilder` wraps an immutable `String`, so why do you want to get a wrapping instance where a `String` doesn't even have to know, that something like a `StringBuilder` exists?

Comment: If you're using Scala you can create an implicit class over the `java.lang.String` class and create your own `.toStringBuilder()` method.

Comment: @JonSkeet : i am just checking the reason why they have not given the same method what they have given in case of stringbuilder class

Answer (score 2):

String itself is **immutable**. That has many advantages, especially with concurrent usage, sharing substrings and such.

Also back and forth coupling between classes is bad design.

Comment: "String itself is immutable". Yes it is. But what's that got to do with the question? .toStringBuilder would not modify the String but make a new StringBuilder with the same content.

Comment: i have same question like Paul ...and coupling is already done in case of stringbuilder.toString();

Comment: @KaribasappaGC: No, there isn't two-way coupling. `StringBuilder` "knows about" `String`, but the `String` API doesn't know about `StringBuilder` at all.

Comment: @Paul yes, there my argumentation is unclear. I meant more or less that a StringBuilder won't back its data to the String. Or so.

Comment: Well,it might. As long as it doesn't modify it, there's no particular reason why StringBuilder shouldn't refer to the original string as its initial contents. It would make (new StringBuilder("Foo")).toString quite efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

`toString` is a method that is part of the `Object` class and thus all classes of java will have such method. A `String` is immutable and as such both `toStringBuilder` and `toStringBuffer` will create new objects. I think that if there were such methods many users would be mislead that using these methods they can modify the string in-place. Also because of the same reasons there can not possible be any more efficient way to create a `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`.

Comment: "many users would be mislead that using these methods they can modify the string in-place" Really? Do people  really think  .toString modifies the actual content of the StringBuilder, rather than making a new String out of it?

Answer (score 0):

You might ask for a considerable number of `String.toFoo()` methods, and where to draw the line?  You can construct `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` using the constructor. That's enough - why add another method?

Comment: we usually do lot of conversions between string and string buffer and string builder..atleast in my experience...so this question comes..its not on any user defined class like Foo

Comment: You have the StringBu*er constructors - why should String be burdened with more methods? What would it achieve? Why would code be better that way?